# Construct XQuery element attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have this XQuery element that is giving me an error:

```
let $mx := 7
for $b in doc("abc.xml")//test
   where $b/@attr = $mx
return 
<mytag myattr="$mx">

{$b/data(@name)}

</mytag>
```

I want to return the value of $mx as the myattr attribute. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use AVTs (Attribute Value Templates) for this**:

```
<mytag myattr="{$mx}">
```